# No enum const class org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameter$ParameterType.DATE - Informix

Tags: spring-batch

So i'm setting up a persistent spring batch (v2.2.2) job repo in an Informix database. I've tweaked the oracle sql script and created my 'BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS' table with this SQL - note the 'DATE_VAL' column is mapped to 'DATE'.

```
CREATE TABLE 'dba'.BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION_PARAMS  (
JOB_EXECUTION_ID INTEGER NOT NULL ,
TYPE_CD CHAR(6) NOT NULL ,
KEY_NAME CHAR(100) NOT NULL ,
STRING_VAL CHAR(250) ,
DATE_VAL DATE DEFAULT NULL ,
LONG_VAL INTEGER ,
DOUBLE_VAL DOUBLE PRECISION ,
IDENTIFYING CHAR(1) NOT NULL ,
foreign key (JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
references BATCH_JOB_EXECUTION(JOB_EXECUTION_ID)
constraint JOB_EXEC_PARAMS_FK 
);
```

I run my first job and can see this row in the table

```
job_execution_id    type_cd key_name    string_val  date_val    long_val    double_val  identifying
2   DATE    RUN_DATE        05/12/2013  0   0.0 Y
```

but my code fails with this exception. Anybody have an idea why the 'type_cd' value of DATE cannot be mapped to the enum type?

```
15:12:27,325 DEBUG [AbstractJob] Job execution starting: JobExecution: id=2, version=0, startTime=null, endTime=null, lastUpdated=Thu Dec 05 15:12:27 GMT 2013, status=STARTING, exitStatus=exitCode=UNKNOWN;exitDescription=, job=[JobInstance: id=2, version=0, Job=[ExtractorJob]], jobParameters=[{RUN_DATE=1386256347064}]
15:12:27,520 ERROR [AbstractJob] Encountered fatal error executing job
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No enum const class org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameter$ParameterType.DATE  
    at java.lang.Enum.valueOf(Enum.java:196)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.JobParameter$ParameterType.valueOf(JobParameter.java:180)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$2.processRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:363)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$RowCallbackHandlerResultSetExtractor.extractData(JdbcTemplate.java:1482)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:686)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:694)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.getJobParameters(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:381)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.access$000(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:61)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$JobExecutionRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:410)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao$JobExecutionRowMapper.mapRow(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:392)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:92)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.RowMapperResultSetExtractor.extractData(RowMapperResultSetExtractor.java:1)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate$1.doInPreparedStatement(JdbcTemplate.java:649)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.execute(JdbcTemplate.java:587)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:637)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:666)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:674)
    at org.springframework.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate.query(JdbcTemplate.java:718)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.dao.JdbcJobExecutionDao.findJobExecutions(JdbcJobExecutionDao.java:130)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.SimpleJobRepository.getLastStepExecution(SimpleJobRepository.java:213)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Due to padding spaces of type `CHAR(6)`. Use `VARCHAR` instead and all should be fine.
(Select text from .DATE to end-of-line in your log and you will notice extra spaces :))